# How to fit a lot of header within cell width using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have copied approximately 88 columns of content from another spreadsheet. The problem is the headers are too big and they are not showing in the column cell properly. So, I had to go to each cell and press Alt+Enter each time. I want to use a macro that will do it automatically.

I am using Microsoft Excel 2016 version.

```
Sub Fit_Headers()

   'Fit_Headers Macro

    Range("BI13").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "ACTUAL SAMPLE " & Chr(10) & "FABRIC INHOUSE DATE"
    Range("BJ13").Select
End Sub
```

I used "Record Macro" to record what I am doing in one cell. How can I modify it so I can use it for remaining cells?`

Comment: If you select the range of columns you want to resize via `.Select` I believe you can do something like `Selection.EntireColumn.Autofit`

Comment: Is not difficult, but at what length you want to break your headers? Word count? Character count? Specific column size?

Comment: `Range("BI13").Value = "ACTUAL SAMPLE " & vbCrLf & "FABRIC INHOUSE DATE"`, then `Range("BI13").EntireColumn.AutoFit` should do. Note, no need to `.Select` anything *or* work with `ActiveCell`, and `.FormulaR1C1` should be used for specifying a R1C1-style formula, but you're assigning a string expression / literal value - `Range.Value` is more appropriate. Macro recorder isn't very smart ;-)

Answer (score 1):

`Chr(10)` is `vbLf`... and it doesn't quite play well with `Range.AutoFit`. `vbNewLine` (`vbCrLf`, i.e. `Chr(10)` & `Chr(13)`) works beautifully though; you don't need to `Select` anything, or to work off the `ActiveCell` at all - that's just macro-recorder junk begging to be cleaned up (recorder merely mimicks [most] user actions, including selecting cells: it doesn't care for redundant or efficient code):

```
Public Sub FitHeaders()
    With ActiveSheet.Range("BI13")
        .Value = "ACTUAL SAMPLE" & vbNewLine & "FABRIC INHOUSE DATE"
        .EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand very well your ask.
Do you want apply the formula `"ACTUAL SAMPLE " & Chr(10) & "FABRIC INHOUSE DATE"` for a different cells ?

Like this :

```
Sub test()
    For Each c In Range("A1:B20").Cells
        c.FormulaR1C1 = "ACTUAL SAMPLE " & Chr(10) & "FABRIC INHOUSE DATE"
    Next c
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with your sample, adding the line of code below after you set the contents of the cell will, I believe, do what you want:

```
ActiveCell.EntireRow.AutoFit
```

There are some limitations that I found while playing with this.  In the example code you provided, you have that Chr(10) bit in there and when that is present, Excel doesn't seem to want to widen the cell to show everything that you have set as a single line on a single line.  It will break the entire string into individual words with each word on a single line within the cell.  Additionally, you can swap the EntireRow with EntireColumn if you have need to.